# Huge .Pack file not being updated on bitbucket server after git-filter-repo

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-filter-branch, git-filter-repo

I am trying to move a folder from an existing bitbucket repository into a new repository and maintain only its history. I was able to copy it using mirror and filtered the branch using the Filter-branch command:

`git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter Ecommerce master`

Where 'Ecommerce' is the folder name and master is the branch I'm trying to filter.

The filter appears to have worked and got rid of all the folders besides the 'Ecommerce' one. The folder only has 5MB of typescript files, but the .pack file inside the .git/objects/pack folder is 1.2 GB.
That seems extremely huge and appears to be lugging around the history for the old repository (which had a lot more code and data files).

So I read up a bit and tried the git-filter-repo command after deleting the tags:

`git filter-repo --path / --invert-paths -f`

This reduces the .pack file to 9MB (which is really good) but it doesn't register as any changes in my local repository git. So I'm not sure how to push it to update the remote repository.

I set the remote:

`git remote add origin https://code.com/myGitRepo.git`

`git push --set-upstream origin master (and with -f)`

I tried clearing the gc

```
git for-each-ref --format='delete %(refname)' refs/original | git update-ref --stdin
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

Even tried: 
`git repack -a -d -f --depth=250 --window=250`

And the 1.2 GB .pack file is still pulled everytime I clone the remote repository, so its definitely not reduced on the remote repo.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ? Or how to update the pack file/history so the repository size is reduced ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbitbucket%5D+reduce+repository+size

Comment: You cannot reduce repo size from the client, you have to it at the server. If the server doesn't belong to you you need to ask admins or support.

Comment: @phd I don't quite understand. I can do filter-branch and push, thats how I filtered it to contain only one folder. I was able to push too. I'm wondering why I can't do a push after a filter-repo ?

Comment: `filter-branch` created new commits. You push new commits and remote repo becomes **bigger**.